# Adding a WHERE clause on a GROUP BY operation

Tags: sql, join, woocommerce, count, mariadb

This query lists out the distinct order numbers in Woocommerce that have order either of two products, where the orders are in a status called 'wc-on-hold'. The query does work, but if I comment back in the AND COUNT(t1.ID)=2 it fails with an invalid use of group function. If I change the WHERE statement to HAVING, it still fails with a syntax error.

```
select distinct t1.id, count(t1.ID) as Products from wp_posts t1
inner join wp_woocommerce_order_items t2 on t1.ID = t2.order_id
inner join wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta t3 on t2.order_item_id = t3.order_item_id
where t3.meta_key = '_product_id' and (t3.meta_value=19549 or t3.meta_value=19547)
and t1.post_status='wc-on-hold'
--and count(t1.ID)=2
group by t1.id
order by count(t1.ID) asc
```

Comment: you can add having after group by

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you put the having clause when you tried it? 
A Having clause needs to be after the group by and before the Order By.
So it would be like this:

```
select distinct t1.id, count(t1.ID) as Products from wp_posts t1
inner join wp_woocommerce_order_items t2 on t1.ID = t2.order_id
inner join wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta t3 on t2.order_item_id = t3.order_item_id
where t3.meta_key = '_product_id' and (t3.meta_value=19549 or t3.meta_value=19547)
and t1.post_status='wc-on-hold'
group by t1.id
having count(t1.id) = 2
order by count(t1.ID) asc
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a `having` clause is what you want. I would phrase your query as:

```
select p.id, count(*) as no_products 
from wp_posts p
inner join wp_woocommerce_order_items oi 
    on p.ID = oi.order_id
inner join wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim 
    on oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
where 
    oim.meta_key = '_product_id' 
    and oim.meta_value in (19549, 19547)
    and p.post_status = 'wc-on-hold'
group by p.id
having count(*) = 2
order by p.id
```

Notes:

- the `having` clause goes *after* the `group by` clause
- meaningful table aliases make the query easier to follow
- `in` comes handy to check the same column against a list of values
- `count(*)` is more efficient than `count(<column>)` (and, here, it is functionaly equivalent)
- ordering by the count is useless, since you are filtering on it already (all rows have the same count)